# Ember Data without Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frameworks, ember-data

I have been using Ember for 1.5 years now and I have to admit: coming from Rails it totally changed the way I am thinking now about web apps. I has shaped my mind that much that I can't even code front-end stuff on Rails.

But I would like to check other frameworks like React or even write my own mini framework. The thing is that I feel ember-data just like Rails ActiveRecord and it's super good and vital on any js app. No need to re-invent the wheel there. So just like AR, is there a way to build a js app and using Ember-Data in order to explot all the functionality that Ember-Data gives (like models, finders, queries, adapters/serializers etc) ?

Has anyone done such a thing? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are libraries like Ember Data for other frameworks, but from my experience, none of them are as good. To name a few, there is JS Data (the successor to Angular Data), Breeze, and dstore.

Comment: in 2022 i still haven't found anything as good as ember-data. `typeorm` needs wasm and decorators. `js-data` isn't maintained. not sure about `rx-db`

Answer (score -1):

Reflux (https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) is the primary choice for a datastore for React. I am not sure about other frameworks. I haven't used it but it is built on a structure called flux that is very well thought out and seems to be getting a lot of traction right now. It is also build around the one way data flow model that React loves to tote(as they should). don't know if it is the right thing for you but it is definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Are you sure reflux is for datastore ?

Comment: @Filippos im pretty sure: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#creating-data-stores

Comment: After working with it, I found out that Reflux is not much related to Ember's Ember Data unfortunately. Sure you can build a simple Ember Data-like architecture, but nowhere close to what Ember Data offers (let alone that I don’t believe that all developers are capable of writing clean, maintainable, testable and scalable code for data stores). :(